# Preserving existing text when writing to file

Tags: vb.net

In `Tester.txt` it simply says "Hello".

I now run this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim aFileStream As FileStream
    Dim aWriter As StreamWriter
    fileName = "...\Tester.txt"
    Try
        aFileStream = New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
        aWriter = New StreamWriter(aFileStream)
        aWriter.WriteLine("World")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("found this {0}", ex.Message)
    Finally
        If aWriter IsNot Nothing Then
            aWriter.Close()
        End If
        If aFileStream IsNot Nothing Then
            aFileStream.Close()
        End If
    End Try

End Sub
```

Now "Hello" has been over-written with "World".

I'd like to preserve the existing text in the file so I thought I could read that text into a variable first and then write the new stuff:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim aFileStream As FileStream
    Dim aWriter As StreamWriter
    Dim aReader As StreamReader
    fileName = "...\Tester.txt"
    Try
        aFileStream = New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)

        aReader = New StreamReader(aFileStream)
        Dim myContent As String = aReader.ReadToEnd()

        aWriter = New StreamWriter(aFileStream)
        aWriter.WriteLine("World")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("found this {0}", ex.Message)
    Finally
        If aWriter IsNot Nothing Then
            aWriter.Close()
        End If
        If aReader IsNot Nothing Then
            aReader.Close()
        End If
        If aFileStream IsNot Nothing Then
            aFileStream.Close()
        End If
    End Try

End Sub
```

Is this the standard way of preserving the text already in the file?
Can I preserve the existing information without using an instance of `StreamReader`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - what you are looking for is called `Append`. For example, you can use [AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext.aspx), if you prefer shared calls (without creating instances of any class). Or via [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx), through [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx). For your case, you can replace this piece:

```
Dim fileName As String
Dim aFileStream As FileStream
Dim aWriter As StreamWriter
fileName = "...\Tester.txt"
Try
    aFileStream = New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    aWriter = New StreamWriter(aFileStream)
    aWriter.WriteLine("World")
```

with this one (note that I also compacted your code into fewer lines with the same result):

```
Dim aWriter As StreamWriter
Try
    aWriter = New StreamWriter("...\Tester.txt", True)
    aWriter.WriteLine("World")
```

And `World` will be appended to the end of your file. If the file does not exist, it will be created, so it already sort of includes `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` behind the scenes.

Using `AppendAllText`, it becomes even shorter:

```
IO.File.AppendAllText("...\Tester.txt", "World")
```

As a side note, you can avoid the need to call this in your `Finally` block:

```
If aReader IsNot Nothing Then
  aReader.Close()
End If
```

If you use the [Using clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx):

```
Using aWriter As New StreamWriter("...\Tester.txt", True)
  aWriter.WriteLine("World")
End Using
```

You can still keep the `Try/Catch` clause, but better change it to catch file-specific exceptions. For example, you could use [IOException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception.aspx).

Comment: +1 for all the extra help - although I already knew StreamWriter has an overloaded constructor I wanted to explicitly create a FileStream in my code.

Comment: @whytheq: if it answers your question, please consider accepting and/or upvoting it.

Comment: [**HERE**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1179880/whytheq?tab=questions) You can see that I eventually mark all answers to questions that I ask - but I ask a lot of questions and like to delay marking them just in case anyone else wants to contribute. (you're keen to hit the 5k mark!)

Comment: @whytheq: Marking an answer does not prevent anyone from contributing. Closing a question does. I just prefer not to leave things unfinished. Besides, it help SO community better provide timely response to other questions, by not looking at the questions, which have been answered. It could be *your* other questions as well.

Comment: ...please don't worry I will definitely mark one answer to **every one** of my questions...(there's no point worrying about points just enjoy sharing your knowledge - but this community shouldn't be about  the points). This is my style when marking answers to _my_ questions. Chances are in a week or so 25points will magically appear in your profile when I mark this correct. Don't take this the wrong way but part of my logic is that it is **my** question so I'll mark it when I'm ready. Your help on my `VB.NET` questions is always appreciated and usually yours are the best answers.

Answer (score 1):

A Normal way to get to the end of tthe would be to use seek.

```
aFileStream.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.End)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use streams? Couldn't you use Io.File functions?
They are really easy to use.
Some examples:

Example 1:

```
IO.File.WriteAllText("Text.txt", "Hello") 'This overwrite file content
```

Example 2:

```
IO.File.AppendAllText("Text.txt", " World") 'This append file content
```

Example 3:

```
Dim FileContent As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("Test.txt")
FileContent &= vbNewLine & "Hi!"
Io.File.WriteAllText("Text2.txt", FileContent)
```

You could event read/write bytes with the equivalent WriteAllBytes, ReadAllBytes..

All the functions can be found here:
[File Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/3z2ck8eh.aspx)

Comment: If the directory is missing, the current working directory will be used ;)

Comment: I see your point, but if the current working directory happens to be the program's directory in a subdirectory of `%PROGRAMFILES%`, then a "normal" user won't be able to write there. I think it's just simpler in the long run to program such that that problem won't arise.

Comment: The OP said fileName = "...\Tester.txt", even if "..." is wrong, it would point into %PROGRAMFILES%\ if the program is placed into %PROGRAMFILES%\foo\, so the problem is the same.