# Write Line to file with stream writer

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have read through how to use streamWriter at [Preserving existing text when writing to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174034/preserving-existing-text-when-writing-to-file)
Yet even though my code is practically the same, no matter what i do nothing gets written to the file. here is the code:

```
Private Sub Main()
Dim todaysdate As String = DateTime.Today
todaysdate = todaysdate.Replace("/", ".")
Dim todayFile As String = "dated\" & todaysdate & ".txt." 
'this just creates the name and filepath that i want my file to be located at

  If File.Exists(todayFile) = False Then

            Dim Day As StreamWriter

            Day = New StreamWriter(todayFile, True)
            Day.WriteLine("sandwhich")
  end if
end sub
```

so yeah, this literally just creates the file (no problem there, the file is made with the correct date and location) but when i open the file it is empty! any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this Code

```
 Dim file_ As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file_ = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(todayFile, True)
        file_.WriteLine("sandwich")
        file_.Close()
```